# In how many permutations of the integers 1,2,...,7 does 1 appear between 2 and 3?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I am missing something in this and I need to discuss it .
Step 1) We can arrange numbers [4 ,7] with $4!$ , different ways . 
Step 2) There are 4 dinstinct cases:

- a) We are going to put '2' , '1' and '3' in 3 of the 5 available
  spaces between numbers [4,8]
  _N_N_N_N_. There are $C(5,3)=10$ ways to do that
- b) We are going to put '21' and '3' or '2' and '13'  there are
  $C(5,2)=10$ to do this    for each case so $2*C(5,2)=20$ in total
  quick fix : I only counted the cases that 2 1 3 come in that order. 
  So to fix this we need to change the positions of 2 and 3 so we have $2!*840=1680$
- c) we are going to put ' 213'    and there are 5 ways to do this

  Sum : $4!*(10 + 20 + 5) = 24 * 35 =
     840$ ways
  But this not the correct answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the cases where $2$ appears first, then $1$, then $3$. However, when the problem asks you to compute permtuations where "$1$ appears between $2$ and $3$," they mean that it is also valid for $3$ to appear first, then $1$, then $2$. For example, in $3415672$, it is valid to say that $1$ is between $2$ and $3$.

It does not take much more work to include these cases, can you see the quick fix?

By they way, there is a quicker way to do this problem. In each of the $7!$ permutations of $\{1,\dots,7\}$, the number of permutations where $1$ is between $2$ and $3$ equals the number of permtuations where $2$ is between $1$ and $3$, which is in turn equal to the number of permutaitons where $3$ is between $1$ and $2$. This is because switching around the names of the numbers does not change the structure of the problem. Since all three of these cases are equal, the number of each must be $7!/3$.

Comment: Oh you are right. I thought that the problem stated that we wanted 2 , 1 , 3 in that order but it makes so much more sense now that all the other choices ( multiple choice question) were larger numbers , thank you!

Comment: @brucebanner Exactly, the quick fix in your edit is correct. If this sufficed to answer your question, can you consider clicking the check mark next to my answer to indicate this?

Comment: i checked it. As for your solution , well i get the part that it does not change the structure of the problem whether 1 2 or 3 comes between , and there is only one way in each case = 3 cases . So if we where to solve the problem every one out the three solutions should have "the same merit" out of the total solution , so we divide it by 3?

Comment: @brucebanner Your comment is correcct.